# Android Video View not support on v2.2

Tags: android, android-videoview

i had developed one application to live streaming video, but it does not support android version 2.2 ,2.3 or etc. only play video on android version 4.1 (Samsung Galaxy Grand).
I am using videoview in my project.
So can you tell me the exact reason.
My code is as follow:

```
mPath.setText("http://iptvshqip.dyndns.tv:8090");       
    mPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
    mPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    mReset = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reset);
    mStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);
            mPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            playVideo();
        }
    });
    mPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.pause();
            }
        }
    });
    mReset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.seekTo(0);
            }
        }
    });
    mStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                current = null;
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
            }
        }
    });
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            playVideo();
        }
    });
  }
 private void playVideo() {
    try {
        final String path = mPath.getText().toString();
        Log.v(TAG, "path: " + path);
        if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File URL/path is empty",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
        else {
            if (path.equals(current) && mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.start();
                mVideoView.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            current = path;
            mVideoView.setVideoPath(getDataSource(path));
            mVideoView.start();
            mVideoView.requestFocus();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        if (mVideoView != null) {
            mVideoView.stopPlayback();
        }
    }
}
   private String getDataSource(String path) throws IOException {
    if (!URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(path)) {
        return path;
    } else {
        URL url = new URL(path);
        URLConnection cn = url.openConnection();
        cn.connect();
        InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
        if (stream == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
        File temp = File.createTempFile("mediaplayertmp", "dat");
        temp.deleteOnExit();
        String tempPath = temp.getAbsolutePath();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(temp);
        byte buf[] = new byte[128];
        do {
            int numread = stream.read(buf);
            if (numread <= 0)
                break;
            out.write(buf, 0, numread);
        } while (true);
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        return tempPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the supported encoding formats and network protocols here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

Android started HTTP Live Stream(HLS) support from 3.0. Read the following link.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/blog/31646/the-pain-of-live-streaming-on-android/

They have explained with workaround.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the [Android `VideoView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) has existed since API level 1.

Except:

- flags `STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN` and `STATUS_BAR_VISIBLE` - deprecated in API 14
- the function `setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background)` deprecated in API 16
- the Public Methods - `canPause()`, `canSeekBackward()` and `canSeekForward()` added in API 5
- `resume()` and  `suspend()` added in API 8
- `onInitializeAccessibilityEvent (AccessibilityEvent event)` and `onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo (AccessibilityNodeInfo info)` added in API 14
- `setOnInfoListener (MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener l)` added in API 17

Do you use any of these? Your problem might be elsewhere anyway.

Please paste some code and describe with more details how is this not working.